# How would you implement a general case for this property mapping to a serializable class object?

Tags: c#, linq

**UPDATE:**
Using temporary constituents from my class object, an iterator was used as a workaround for the z[index] issue inside the lambda expressions per below.

Here is the snippet:

```
var yValues = new List<Schema.W[]>();
Schema.W[] y = null;
for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
    {
        y= data
            .Select((z) => new Schema.W
                {
                    property_0 = z[0],
                    property_1 = decimal.Parse(z[i + 1])
                }).ToArray();
                    yValues.Add(y);
                }
    }
```

And then finally:

```
var finalList = new List<Schema.W>();
Schema.W = null;
for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
    {
        mapping = new Schema.W
        {
            innerNodes = yValues[i]
        };
                finalList.Add(mapping);
    }
```

### **Update**: LINQ solution found. Code review completed off-site.

I have used the serialization facilities in .NET to transform an *.XML file into a class object, which represents the data model of a third-party black box application.

Using LINQ, I was able to map my column headers of a data matrix into their constituent properties sitting in this class object, and serialize out to a temporary *.XML test file with good results. The solution was as follows:

```
Schema.W[] mapping = headers
                .Select((x, index) => new Schema.W
                {
// String headers (except for the first column) - "Dates" are excluded from headers 
                    property_0 = headers[index], 
                    property_1 = y
                }).ToArray();

Schema.Entry[] y = data
                 .Select((z, index) => new W.Entry
                 {
                     property_0 = z[0],
                     property_1= decimal.Parse(z[index]) // breaks when z[index]
                }).ToArray();
```

However, when I attempt to apply the same idiom to y, an issue occurs with the indexer. For the first property ("Date") of the inner XML node I am mapping into, the property mapping works correctly, as this is the first column of my data matrix, and is denoted by a hard-coded value (e.g. z[0]).

However, my second property ("Value"), is running into (a) an out of bounds problem with Value = decimal.Parse(z[index]) and (b) a type problem when I am attempting to extract single values from a processing step where I store numeric information in an IEnumerable. The issue arises when I attempt to write each columns' numbers into the property_1 field, which later outputs into a serialized XML file with the following structure:

```
<W>
  <Overrides>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2001-01</property_0>
        <property_1>90.01</property_1>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2002-01</property_0>
        <property_1>90.02</property_1>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2003-01</property_0>
        <property_1>90.03</property_1>
      </Entry>
  </Overrides>
</W>
<W>
  <Overrides>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2001-01</property_0>
        <property_1>90.01</property_1>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2002-01</property_0>
        <property_1>90.02</property_1>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2003-01</property_0>
        <property_1>90.03</property_1>
      </Entry>
  </Overrides>
</W>
```

Currently, the contents of the second column are being written out to the second  node, whereas the contents of the third column in my CSV file should be written out (property_1 = {9001, 9002, 9003}).

I have tried the following:
a. Apply LINQ sequences to a CSV data matrix *without* a Date column (e.g. property_0) and only apply my Selects to the numeric values (e.g. [[90.01, 90.02, 90.03], [9001, 9002, 9003]].
b. Use FileHelpers to "Ignore" the first column when mapping into my class object.

What I would like in the end is:

```
<W>
  <Overrides>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2001-01</property_0>
        <property_1>90.01</property_1>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2002-01</property_0>
        <property_1>90.02</property_1>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2003-01</property_0>
        <property_1>90.03</property_1>
      </Entry>
  </Overrides>
</W>
<W>
  <Overrides>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2001-01</property_0>
        <property_1>9001</property_1>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2002-01</property_0>
        <property_1>9002</property_1>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <property_0>2003-01</property_0>
        <property_1>9003</property_1>
      </Entry>
  </Overrides>
</W>
```

Any guidance related to refactoring this solution set would also be highly appreciated. This is a last resort for me - and perhaps I will get a bit of flack for this being my first post without contributions attached to my profile [rightly so]. Documentation does not help with semantics, unfortunately.

Thank you, everybody. A lot of us would be left clueless without Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Here is a refactored method for the below snippets, and what is ultimately a more elegant solution for the original question...
New code starts here:

```
private static Schema.W[] Map(string[] headers, IEnumerable<string[]> data)
{
    Schema.W[] mapping = headers
        .Select((x, index) => new Schema.W
        {
            property_0 = x,   
            property_1 = data
                .Select((z) => new Schema.WEntry
                {
                    child_0 = z[0],
                    child_1 = z[index + 1]
                }).ToArray()
        }).ToArray();
    return mapping;
}
```

Old code starts here:

```
var yValues = new List<Schema.W[]>();
Schema.W[] y = null;
for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
    {
        y = data
            .Select((z) => new Schema.W
                {
                    property_0 = z[0],
                    property_1 = decimal.Parse(z[i + 1])
                }).ToArray();
                    yValues.Add(y);
                }
    }
```

And then finally:

```
var finalList = new List<Schema.W>();
Schema.W = null;
for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
    {
        mapping = new Schema.W
        {
            innerNodes = yValues[i]
        };
                finalList.Add(mapping);
    }
```